# ¿Como cambiar la codificación de caracteres para que mi FileWriter escriba en formato ISO_8859-1?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa que lee un archivo de texto, cambia el formato de una fecha especifica (Fecha de Emisión) y luego vuelve a escribir todo en un archivo diferente con el formato de fecha correcta.

El tema es que cuando vuelve a escribir el archivo lo hace en UTF-8 y yo necesito que lo reescriba en **ISO_8859-1**

¿ Como puedo hacer esto ?

```
public class DateFormater {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if(args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("Faltan argumentos");
            return;
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Leyendo Archivos de Configuración ... ");
            Configuration conf = new Configuration("../resources/Configuracion.json");

            final String origin = (String) conf.getJson().get("origen") +args[0];
            final String destiny = (String) conf.getJson().get("destino")+args[1];
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(origin);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(destiny);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                if(strLine.contains("Fecha de Emision: ")){
                    String date = strLine.substring(83,93);
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
                    String dateString = format.format(new Date(date));
                    String newDate = strLine.replace(date, dateString);
                    writer.write(newDate+"\n");
                }
                else{
                    writer.write(strLine+"\n");
                }
            }
            br.close();
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("El programa ha finalizado con exito");
            System.out.println("El nuevo archivo ha sido generado en " + destiny);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DateFormater.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DateFormater.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, existe una forma de especifica de realizar el cambio de encoding sobre la clase FileWriter. Para lograr lo que buscas tienes que realizar tu desarrollo de otro forma, por ej:

```
private static final String SALIDA = "/Users/abcd/samples/salida.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(SALIDA),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
    osw.write("Hola mundo\n");
    osw.close();
}
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que escribir el archivo en ISO-8859-1 no garantiza la conversión de los datos escritos, por ej: si lees un dato en UTF-8 en una variable y luego escribes tal dato al archivo NO se efectuará la conversión de los bytes escritos, tendrás primero que convertir la información a ISO-8859-1 y luego si escribir el dato, podrías realizar la conversión previa así:

```
new String("Cadena leida en UTF-8".getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
```

Comment: Hmmmm, me imagine que tendría que cambiar el código! Muchas gracias hermano

Comment: Voy a tratar más tarde, si me sirve te acepto la pregunta luego

Comment: Bueno, andar anda, pero sigue sin reconocerme las Ñ y los acentos !! :/

Comment: Ojo, no por escribir el archivo con encoding ISO-8859-1 quiere decir que la información cargada en alguna variable y que es UTF-8 se vaya a convertir automaticamente a ISO-8859-1

Comment: Gracias hermano por la enseñanza, todos los días aprendo algo nuevo con ustedes ! Te mando un abrazo!